# python OpenAI API RateLimitError

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api

I just used example from openai documentation...

```
import openai
openai.api_key = 'my-api'
completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Hello world"}])
print(completion.choices[0].message.content)
```

...and got RateLimitError...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\PycharmProjects\game\test_tg.py", line 3, in <module>
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Hello world"}])
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\PycharmProjects\game\venv\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\chat_completion.py", line 25, in create
    return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\PycharmProjects\game\venv\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py", line 155, in create
    response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\PycharmProjects\game\venv\lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 299, in request
    resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\PycharmProjects\game\venv\lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 710, in _interpret_response
    self._interpret_response_line(
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\PycharmProjects\game\venv\lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 775, in _interpret_response_line
    raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.
```

...even my token have never been used
[image]

What the problem is?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've having same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to upgrade your plan to a paid plan.

You get this error because you have hit your assigned rate limit.

[image]

[RateLimitError](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/python-library-error-types)

[Rate Limit Guide](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/overview)

Once you have upgraded your plan generate a new API key and wait for a while so that it reflects on your account.

Comment: but I have never used it, how could I hit my rate limit?